# Populating select and input box based on a table using PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table cene_pretplatne_stanarske which has two columns 'lice' and 'cene'. The first column 'lice' should populate a select, dropdown menu, and the other column, 'cene', should populate a input box, based on the selection of the dropdown menu. I tried this:

```
<?php

mysql_connect('localhost', 'xxxxx', 'xxxxxxx');
mysql_select_db('xxxxxxx');
mysql_set_charset('utf8');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM cene_pretplatne_stanarske";
$result = mysql_query($sql);
$row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result);
$cena = $row ["cena"];
$sql = "SELECT lice FROM cene_pretplatne_stanarske WHERE lice LIKE 'C0%'";
$result = mysql_query($sql);

echo "<select name='lice' onchange='document.getElementById(\'form1\').submit();'>";
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) 
{
echo "<option value='" . $row['lice'] . "'>" . $row['lice'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='text' value='$cena' />";
?>
```

but it returns empty select box, and the input box with the value of the first row of 'cene' column. Please help.

Comment: Please, don't use mysql_* functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, here is [good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: use to find error: $result = mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))

Comment: There isn't an error in the query. Is the coding for select and input boxes good?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check how many (if any) results are being returned:

```
$i=0;

while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    echo "<option value='" . $row['lice'] . "'>" . $row['lice'] . "</option>";
    $i++;
}
```

`echo $i` after the end of `</select>`